# How to specify elements belonging to the same class in HTML?

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

How can I specify the first `p` element of each `li` tag belongs to the same class without doing it manually (in the case there are too many `li` tags in the `ul` element), as we know that `:first-child` pseudo-class only applies `style` attribute for element, not `class` attribute?

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can't a class is just an identifier to select them with javascript or CSS. It is not the same as a class in an object orientated programming language. but you can use use `li > p:first-child` as selector in CSS

Comment: A class attribute is used for selecting elements, why do you need to select these elements? (CSS and JS both have ways to select these elements, but we can't give a good answer without understanding what you are trying to do)

Comment: @DBS in the case I have a code that the other gave it to me, and I want to modify it

Comment: :first-child is a way of selecting, it has nothing to do with attributes (style or otherwise).

Comment: If you really need to add an actual class to each of the first li elements, you'll need to use Javascript. CSS has no way of altering the DOM's contents.

Comment: @DuyDuy But why do you want to modify it, what is the end goal? What will those classes be used for? (Right now this sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `li > p:first-child` as selector in the CSS:

```css
li > p:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you really want to add a class to those elements then you can use JavaScript for it and the `classList.add()` function:

```js
const FirstParagraph = document.querySelectorAll('li > p:first-child');
FirstParagraph.forEach(paragraph => {
  paragraph.classList.add('bg-red');
})
```

```css
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I get it your question or not. But my understanding is you want to select paragraphs that shares some specific class that under li element. If that is the case you can inspect the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p class="xyz">...</p>
                <p>...</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="xyz">...</p>
                <p class="xyz">...</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="zyx">...</p>
                <p class="ldk2">...</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            const getParagraphElements = (givenClass) => {
                const liList = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];
                const neededParagraphs = [];
                liList.forEach((li) => {
                    const firstChildren = li.children[0];
                    if (firstChildren.classList.contains(givenClass)) {
                        neededParagraphs.push(firstChildren);
                    }
                });
                console.log(neededParagraphs);
            };

            getParagraphElements("xyz");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```